# How to display each row data in the database?

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I'm having a hard time displaying the title and note on each row of my database. I want to display one row (with the title and note) after each
from a form in a page heading to the displaying of row datas page.

This is my code below:

//
Let's say that we have 4 rows of datas. In my code, I can only display the first row, because it keeps having the first row's data. This is because the form is in the first php file. Then after I submit the form, it's directed to this file, and it keeps getting the first row.

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");?>
<?php $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note"); ?>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>

<?php
$id=$row['id'];
 echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
    echo '<button class="call_modal" data-id="$id" style="cursor:pointer;">'. $row['title'] . '</button>';
?>
<?php
}?>
<?php $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note"); ?>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
<div class="note" data-id="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal_close close"></div>
<div class="modal_main">

<?php
   echo '<br><br>';

       echo '<div class="padding">'.$row['title'].'';
        echo '<br><br><br><br>';
    echo ''.$row['note'].'</div>';
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}?>
<?php
<?php
function test_input($data) { 
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
} ?>
```

Comment: You dont need a `<?php ... ?>` on every line! Will make the code easier to read and debug if you dont

Comment: Hi Patrick, other than a couple of missing/unnecessary php tags your code looks like it should work... can you give us more details about what errors you are getting or what is/IS NOT happening?

Comment: Let's say that we have 4 rows of datas, I'n my code, I can only display the first row, because it keeps having the first row datas, because the form is in the first php file, then after I submit the form, it's directed to this file and it keeps getting the first row

Comment: Yeah sorry I overlooked a key line here that would be causing an issue. I am putting together some sample code that will help you understand what the problem is. Just a sec..

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you're using [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), which returns an array with each element in that array containing the field value.

What you want is [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead, this will return a hash which you can then use the way you're using it now.

Another thing is that you don't need to have 2 loops in there querying the database. And please indent your code, it makes it really hard for you and everyone else to read it.

Here is the updated/cleaned up version of your code. This has been tested, you can find a sample code with instructions to run on my Github [here](https://github.com/samerziade/so-54443795).

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "task");
$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
  echo '<button class="call_modal" data-id="' . $id . '" style="cursor:pointer;">'. $row['title'] . '</button>';
  ?>
  <div class="note" data-id="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal_close close"></div>
        <div class="modal_main">
          <?php
          echo '<br /><br />';
          echo '<div class="padding">' . $row['title'];
          echo '<br /><br /><br /><br />';
          echo $row['note'];
          echo '</div>'
          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>

<?php
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it sooner because I have a class, I'll just update a comment

Comment: No problem, let me know if this helps

Comment: dude I there's a problem, I get all the datas in the last row data for all buttons

Comment: It keeps me having the last row datas in my database for all modals

Comment: SIr, it did not work because I keep on getting the last datas in the database

Comment: @patrickesguerra, I just tested that code and it's returning all the records from the table. Are you sure you have more than one record in the database?

Comment: yes, after I add a record and display it in that code, It replaces the past datas into the last data row added

Comment: It seems that you have another problem which is not related to the code you're displaying. I updated my answer above to include a link to a running example on my Github. Please take a look at it and try to troubleshoot it from there.

Comment: Where do we use/put .gitnore, db.conf, docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile?

Comment: Do you have a tutorial on how to do it? :/

Comment: You're supposed to clone the repository, instructions are in the README file. You'll need to have Docker installed as well.

Comment: Also @patrickesguerra, this thread is going beyond the scope of your question. Please search online on how to use Docker, Git, etc.

Comment: Another thing is that you removed my post as being the answer. I believe I've answered your question, with more than enough examples and samples to go with.

Comment: I was wrong, it replaces past datas with the new inserted data

Comment: Do you mind giving an instruction on how to work on the link ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not tested but it should be correct and give you a better idea of what you are doing right/wrong. I hope it helps..

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
$results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note");



while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { //starting your data row loop


$id=$row['id'];// you are creating a variable here but not using it two lines down. 
 echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
 //YOUR OLD CODE echo '<button class="call_modal" data-id="$id" style="cursor:pointer;">'. $row['title'] . '</button>';
 echo '<button class="call_modal" data-id="$id" style="cursor:pointer;">'. $id . '</button>';// use the variable "$id" that you created here

// You dont need the next two lines, you already did a query and have the data loaded in the "$results" array
/*  $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM note"); 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) */

?> // close the php tag if you are going to switch to html instead of "echoing html"
/* OLD CODE <div class="note" data-id="<?= $row['id'] ?>"> you were missing the "php" in the php tags */
<div class="note" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"> // corrected code
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal_close close"></div>
<div class="modal_main">

<?php //switching back to php so create your open tag again...
   echo '<br><br>';

       echo '<div class="padding">'.$row['title'].'';
        echo '<br><br><br><br>';
    echo ''.$row['note'].'</div>';// you dont NEED the '' before .$row....  unless you want it but its just essentially a blank string
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
} // ending your "for each data row" here 
?>

<?php
//  PS you're not using this function anywhere unless its in ommited code?
function test_input($data) { 
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
} ?>
```

Comment: I'll try it sooner, because I have a class, I'll just update a comment